# How to write out a 3D array in javascript manually

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to write the contents of a table row (address) from PHP to javascript.

However I cannot find anywhere that mentions the syntax for it.

Currently I am just using the PHP syntax, i.e. (with '=>')

```
var addresses = [
'0' => ['add1' => '1 Smith Lane','add2'='London','postcode'=>'333 444'],
'1' => ['add1' => '2 Smith Lane','add2'='Wales','postcode'=>'555 333']
]
```

Is there anything wrong with this? All i get is Unexpected Token: ILLEGAL.

So there must be something wrong with it :P lol

Comment: You need to use objects, as arrays in javascript cannot have associative keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript syntax for arrays is :

```
var array = [ ];
```

Javascript syntax for objects is :

```
var object = { };
```

From PHP think of an array as numerically indexed, an object is equivalent to an associative array (this doesn't truly do justice to objects in JS but will give you a starting point).

You're array therefore would be something along these lines in JS.

```
var addresses = [
    {add1 : '1 Smith Lane', add2 : 'London'},
    {add1 : '2 Smith Lane', add2 : 'Wales'}
];
```

Comment: Ah, so it is effectively an array of objects then?

Comment: And how then can I reference this data, say, with an alert? If I wanted to reference 'add2' for instance?

Comment: Just tried `alert(addresses[0]['add1']);` and it worked! thank you.

Comment: Yeah that's right. You could also use `addresses[0].add1` to access object properties.

Comment: Just to add, if you you converted your PHP array to JSON and you parsed it as JSON in Javascript. You can access it exactly the same way `addresses[0]['add1']`

Comment: Thank you! I actually did go with the JSON approach in the end, as dap.tci mentioned below, because it was a lot less code.  I was aware of JSON before but I had never used it.  Turns out it was just what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
var addresses = [
    {'add1' : '1 Smith Lane', 'add2' : 'London', 'postcode' : '333 444'},
    {'add1' : '2 Smith Lane', 'add2' : 'Wales', 'postcode' : '555 333'}
]
```

Or, you could convert your PHP array to JSON:

```
var addresses = <?= json_encode($arrayPHP) ?>;
```

Comment: Im intrigued about the JSON, as I've never really used JSON.  With the 'array' or the 'object' being the way it is structured, if I used your JSON code, how would I access 'add1' from javascript?

Comment: Okay, so your code missed out the quotation marks, but I like the JSON approach.  I am going with this in the end.  For future reference, to write out 'add1', I would reference it like this: `console.log(addresses[0].add1);`

Comment: Isn't it possible to just directly put the json into your variable? json is perfectly fine as javascript.

Comment: Ooh okay! I didnt know that :) I have amended my code! Thank you!